# Tensorflow examples as rows or columns?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Given the Tensorflow API `nn.softmax`, `nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, `tf.nn.rnn` etc. it seems that the convention is to have the samples placed as rows in a batch.

A forward pass in a neural network is then `tf.matmul(input_batch, W) + b`, where `input_batch` is a matrix of shape `[n_samples, input_size]`. The `n_samples` is often named `batch_size` in the API. The addition of the row vector `b` is broadcasted on all samples(rows) in the batch.

Is this a general adopted convention when working with neural networks? I have read a lot of research articles that have the samples as columns and use left multiplication of the weight matrix for a forward pass. Why was this convention chosed?

EDIT

This article uses multiplication of the weight matrix on the left side of the input, as well as vector concatenation, so the samples must be  columns:
http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/. It is referred to in the Tensorflow documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/recurrent/index.html.

---

The implementation of BasicLSTMCell is based on this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2329v5.pdf according to the source here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py. You also see multiplication from the left.

---

Finally in this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00019.pdf, the activations are also column vectors.

Comment: Examples are usually 0'th dimension (ie, batch dimension). I think the reason is that this dimension usually exists, which other dimensions are optional, so it made sense to make it the first one

Answer (score 0):

I think this is purely a matter of convention and (most) machine learning researchers and practitioners have agreed to adopt the `[n_samples, input_size]` convention. One advantage becomes evident when you one instance is not a vector with `d` elements, but a general `[d1, d2, ..., dm]` array (e.g. one instance being a `[width, height, 3]` RGB image). With the `[n_samples, input_size]` convention, you can always rely on the first index being the sample size.

Comment: Thanks, but a lot of research articles shows the other way, see my edit. Good point though, that the inputs can have different dimensions, but then it is API convention, not matrix multiplication anymore.